# Write only, read only fields in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have models like this:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class ModelB(models.Model):
    f1 = models.CharField()
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

Serializers:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_b_ids = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        write_only_fields = ('model_b_ids',)
```

views:

```
class AView(CreateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):

    def perform_create(self, serializer): 
        model_b_ids = parse_somehow(serializer.validated_data["model_b_ids"])
        #do something...
```

The problem I am getting is the with the "model_b_ids"

The user should submit it while sending post data.

I use it in perform_create to link to related models.

But thats not "real column" in ModelA so when I try to save it is raising exception.

I tried to it pop from validated_data but then again getting error somewhere that cannot read model_b_ids from model. Any idea on using this kind of field correctly ?

Answer (score 194):

The Django Rest Framework does not have Meta attribute `write_only_fields` anymore

According to their **[docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)** you set write-only fields in extra_kwargs

e.g

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    ``Serializer`` for ``User`` ..
    """

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name' ,'security_question', 'security_question_answer', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff')
        read_only_fields = ('is_active', 'is_staff')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'security_question': {'write_only': True},
            'security_question_answer': {'write_only': True},
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }
```

## Update

As @AKHIL MATHEW highlighted in his answer below

From DRF v3 onwards, setting a field as read-only or write-only can use serializer field core arguments mentioned as follows.

**write_only**

> Set this to True to ensure that the field may be used when updating or creating an instance, but is not included when serializing the representation.

Defaults to False
Eg:

`company = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(write_only=True)`

Comment: Please find my answer below for the latest approach in the DRF version 3

Answer (score 72):

In accordance with the Django REST Framework [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.0-announcement/#the-extra_kwargs-option):

> The write_only_fields option on ModelSerializer has been moved to PendingDeprecation and replaced with a more generic extra_kwargs

that's why it's recommended to do like this: you should use extra_kwargs:

```
extra_kwargs = {
    'model_b_ids': {'write_only': True},
    'another_field': {'read_only': True}
}
```

or:

```
 model_b_ids = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
```

Comment: I just updated DRF from 3.1.3 to 3.3.3 and suddenly my Users' passwords were being sent back (I had before the `write_only` Meta atribute. Your solution fixes this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @vabada I hope you mean hashes 

Answer (score 14):

From DRF v3 onwards, setting a field as read-only or write-only can use serializer field core arguments mentioned as follows.

**Core arguments**

> Each serializer field class constructor takes at least
> these arguments. Some Field classes take additional, field-specific
> arguments, but the following should always be accepted:

**read_only**

> Read-only fields are included in the API output but should
> not be included in the input during create or update operations. Any
> 'read_only' fields that are incorrectly included in the serializer
> input will be ignored.
>
> Set this to True to ensure that the field is used when serializing a
> representation, but is not used when creating or updating an instance
> during deserialization.
>
> Defaults to False

Eg:

```
price = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
```

**write_only**

> Set this to True to ensure that the field may be used when
> updating or creating an instance, but is not included when serializing
> the representation.
>
> Defaults to False

Eg:

```
company = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(write_only=True)
```

Answer (score 10):

Probably you're overseeing that your `ModelA` has the property `modelb_set`. In Django you describe the relationship in one model class. Django offers a backward relationship by lower-casing the target model and suffixing it with `_set`. So you could do:

```
a = ModelA.objects.get(pk=1)
a.modelb_set.all()
```

This would get the element with ID (or primary key) 1 from ModelA and retrieve all related ModelB elements.

You can set a value for `related_name` to overwrite the default value:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    f1 = models.CharField()
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name='model_b')
```

In DRF you can slightly adapt your serializer:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_b = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        write_only_fields = ('model_b',)
```

With `serializers.CharField()` you can't post values and write them to the model, because it isn't a model field.

Give this example a try. Tinker and experiment. It should bring you closer to the solution.

EDIT:
I'm not really sure how Django creates the name for backward relationship for PascalCase class names. Is it `model_b_set` for `ModelB`? Or is it `modelb_set`? You can try and find it out.

Comment: `write_only_fields` is no longer valid with Django version 3. Instead they suggested to use `extra_kwargs` like this-
`extra_kwargs = { "model_b": {"write_only": True, },}`

Answer (score 7):

From [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only) you can use `read_only`

> Read-only fields are included in the API output, but should not be included in the input during create or update operations. Any 'read_only' fields that are incorrectly included in the serializer input will be ignored.
>
> Set this to True to ensure that the field is used when serializing a representation, but is not used when creating or updating an instance during deserialization.
>
> Defaults to `False`

As example:

We can use it on Serializer fields:

```
model_b_ids = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
```

or we can use it in `extra_kwargs`:

```
extra_kwargs = {
    'model_b_ids': {'read_only': True}
}
```

Comment: Ellusive, but this is the way it works in Django 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Well you could override the serializer.save() method on ASerializer to instantiate modelA object, set its attributes, save it, then set relations on existing modelB objects, save them as well and drink to success.
But I think maybe setting that related_name and RelatedField on serializer as was suggested would do exactly the same thing.... with less typing.. and overall better:)