# How to get data from multiple models in djago rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am new in Django Rest APi so Please help.

I have Two models :

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dept_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete= models.CASCADE)'
```

And Respective serializers are:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'

class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = '__all__'
```

I want to retrieve the data in like this

```
{
    emptId : 1,
    empName : 'John',
    empEmail : 'John@gmail.com',
    empMobile : '1111111111',
    deptId : 1,
    deptName : 'Accounts',
    deptLocation : 'Pune',
    deptCode : 'ACC'
}
```

How to get the above data. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Your `Serializers.py`

```
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = '__all__'

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    department = DepartmentSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('empId','empName','empEmail','empMobile','department')
```

using this you will get nested object structure which is preferred.

If you want to get flatten structure then

```
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = '__all__'

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    department = DepartmentSerializer(many=False)
    depId = serializers.IntergerField(source='department.id')
    depName = serializers.CharField(source='department.name')
    depLocation = serializers.CharField(source='department.location')
    depCode = serializers.CharField(source='department.dept_code')
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('empId','empName','empEmail','empMobile','depId','depName','depLocation','depCode','department')
```

Hope you get this
If you don't want `department` object in get method then add `write_only=True` in argument of department field.

see more 
[readonly and writeonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989915/write-only-read-only-fields-in-django-rest-framework)

[medium](https://medium.com/@sarit.r/read-only-write-only-in-django-rest-serializer-670935a710f4)

Answer (score 1):

You can write your serializer class like this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    emptId = serializers.IntergerField()
    empName = serializers.CharField()
    empEmail = serializes.CharField()
    empMobile = serializes.CharField()
    depId = serializers.IntergerField()
    depName = serializers.CharField()
    depLocation = serializers.CharField()
    depCode = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('emptId', 'empName', 'empEmail', 'empMobile', 'depId', 'depName', 'depLocation', 'depCode',)
```

And you can write your view class like this:

```
class MyAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        employeeId = 1
        myEmployee = Employee.objects.filter(id=employeeId) \
                                     .annotate(emptId=F('id'),
                                               empName=F('name'),
                                               empEmail=F('email'),
                                               empMobile=F('mobile'),
                                               depId=F('department__id'),
                                               depName=F('department__name'),
                                               depLocation=F('department__location')
                                               depCode=F('department__dep_code').values('emptId', 'empName', 'empEmail', 'empMobile', 'depId', 'depName', 'depLocation', 'depCode').first()

        mySerializer = MySerializer(myEmployee)
        return Response(mySerializer, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I do not test the code in a real program. But you can write your code like my code. You can inspire of that.